# Instant print screen

Tags: windows-10, printing

This is probably obvious, but is there a way to make the print-screen button print the screen?

No pasting to paint or other long solutions. I need it to work everywhere, including in games.

Windows 10. Print the screen, with a printer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give ShareX a try.
You can set the default action to print.

[image: Direct to printer]

Under the capture menu you can do full screen.
[image]

There is also this option if you are getting a confirmation dialog:
[image]

Comment: Nothing automatic, but this is pretty fast.